# MOV instruction limitations

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

Why can't an immediate value be moved into a segment registry directly (i.e. mov ds 10) ?

Also, why cannot segment registers be copied directly (i.e mov es, ds) ?

```
.code
        mov AX,@data
        mov DS,AX
```

Why can't this be done directly by:

```
        mov DS, @data
```

Any explanation why it was designed this way?

Comment: *Presumably* you're talking x86, x64 architectures? There are others, you know, and some of them *don't* suffer the lack of orthogonality evident in the x86 instruction set. Please add a suitable tag.

Comment: Please restate your question, maybe adding some real example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is Instruction en-/decoding

X86 has opcodes with variable lengths. They can range from a single byte (like nop) to a couple of bytes, like 12 bytes for something like movl $0xdeadbeef, 0x12345678(%ebx,%edx,1)
Intel decided to not include instructions which provide no real advantage. mov segmentregister,  is one of them. Most probably because segmentregisters do not have to be changed very often.

So, this saves space in the instruction encoding and so it saves a couple of transistors on the chip (compared to transistors dumps today, maybe not THAT much).

Other ISAs like ARM or MIPS which have a fixed encoding size for their instructions usually allow the same operations for all registers. In the case of ARM even the PC is a normal register and can be read an written too.

Answer (score 2):

Because there was no need to edit those registry (except in some rare circumstances) since they are set by the operating system. So why waste silicon doing something useless?

You can edit those registry via another temporary one though.